# Kubernetes deployment unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].PersistentVolumeClaim"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Hi got a YAML that seems valid to me but it does not work when applying it and I can't figure out what is wrong with it

error:

```
unknown field "spec.template.spec.volumes[0].PersistentVolumeClaim"
```

kubeval deployment.yaml passes with no errors

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-service
  namespace: app-1-0
  labels:
    app: app-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          image: registry.azurecr.io/app/app-service:1.0
          env:
          - name: AzureAd__Instance
            value: ...
          - name: AzureAd__ClientId
            value: ...
          - name: AzureAd__TenantId
            value: ...
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
              name: cache
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      volumes:
      - name: cache
        PersistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: app-pvc
```

Comment: you need to define filed in camelcase as in everywhere `persistentVolumeClaim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `persistentVolumeClaim` should be lowercased and specified as a nested object under volumes.

```
volumes:
  - name: cache 
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: app-pvc
```